# Which class does a method defined inside a block belong to?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.3

Here's a class

```
class Foo
  def test_method(&c)
    puts "inside test method"
    c.call
  end
end
```

Now, if I define a method inside the block

```
f = Foo.new
f.test_method do 
  def m1
    puts "inside the method m1 defined inside the block"
  end
  puts m1.class
end
```

The output of the block is `NilClass`

If a method is defined outside a class it becomes a private method inside the class `Object`. Why does a method defined inside a block become a part of `NilClass` and not of the class `Foo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `m1` returns the result of `puts`, which is `nil`.

Second, with your current code, `m1` method is defined for `Object` class, because block by default remains its context, not only for local variables (which it does always), but also for 'current object' and 'current class'. If you want your definition work as you expect, you can use `class_eval`, which changes the current class inside of the block (executes this block in different context:

```
class Foo
  def test_method(&c)
    puts 'inside test method'
    self.class.class_eval(&c)
  end
end
f = Foo.new
f.test_method do
  def m1
    # anything
  end
end

Foo.instance_methods.grep(/m1/)
# => [:m1]
f.m1
# => not an error
Object.new.m1
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `m1' for #<Object:0x00000001c9b4f8>
```

Comment: @mudasobwa fair point, I edited my answer. It turns out `instance_eval` adds `m1` method as singleton method of the object on which `instance_eval` was called.

Comment: I was working with helpers in Sinatra. In Sinatra, helpers are defined in a helper block - `helpers do ... end`. Does this work according to the technique that you've mentioned here?

Comment: @dhaliman as far as I can see, yes, it does:

https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/17b4253b209c7f537f67bb984774b4933b9147b4/sinatra-contrib/lib/sinatra/namespace.rb#L233

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the class the method is defined on, you should do it explicitly:

```
Foo.new.test_method do 
  def m1; :content_does_not_matter; end
  puts method(:m1).inspect
end  
#⇒ #<Method: Object#m1>
```

One might use [`Method#owner`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-owner) to retrieve the owner:

```
method(:m1).owner
#⇒ Object
```